# Validating String and Type Conversion in JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript

I'm coming from a C# background. I'm currently doing some development in JavaScript. I have some values that passed in. However, I'm not sure how 'best' to validate and convert them. For instance, in C#, I have code that looks like this:

```
Guid id = Guid.Empty;
if (Guid.TryParse(getIDString(), out id) == false)
  throw new Exception("Invalid GUID");

int year = 0;
if (Int32.TryParse(getYearString(), out year) == false)
  throw new Exception("Invalid Year");

if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(getStringValue()))
  throw new Exception("String is required.");

DateTime createdOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
if (DateTime.TryParse(getDateString(), out createdOn) == false)
  throw new Exception("Invalid Creation Date");

decimal? latitude = null;
decimal temp = 0;
if (Decimal.TryParse(GetLatitudeString(), out temp) == false)
  throw new Exception("Invalid latitude");
else
  latitude = temp;
```

I feel I have two seperate issues converting this code to JavaScript: 1. Parsing strings and 2. Type conversions.

In JavaScript, I can't figure out how to do a `String.IsNullOrEmpty()`. I thought there would be a comparable function in lodash. However, I didn't see one. The whole null vs undefined thing kind of throws a kink in my understanding of how to best write this code. Even then, I'm not sure what the recommended way is of attempting to convert values from strings to meaningful data types in JavaScript. I want to throw an error if the conversion doesn't work. Yet, I'm not sure how to do that in JavaScript.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The `int` and `decimal` pieces aren't translatable directly to JavaScript since there's just a `Number` type

Comment: The `== false` seems like a strange usage of C# to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript does not have static typing. This may not be a problem, if you are in full control of your code and how it is used. But if your code is called from outside and you rely on certain variables to have certain types, you may have to check them with `typeof variable`.

- GUID: There is no such type as a GUID in javascript, but you could check your GUID with a regular expression.
- int/decimal: there are the `parseInt()` and `parseFloat()` functions. Then you should check with `isNaN` (not a number)
- String: a very easy check could be `!variable` which will return true for undefined, null, '', and 0
- Date: you could check whether `new Date(variable).getTime()` is NaN
- Exception handling/throwing: Javascript has try/catch and throw like c#
- undefined vs. null: Unless you are in strict mode, you do not need to declare variables in advance. Undefined means the variable is not defined in the current scope. Null means it is declared, but assigned a null value.